# move and animate sprite horizontally when scrolling vertically

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, parallax

I'm trying to replicate the effect made famous by the "ben the bodyguard" website.

Specifically I'm trying to have a sprite image moving horizontally on the screen when scrolling vertically the page. So it's a 2 step effect:

- Scroll horizontally
- Animate the sprite (this is the one they are using http://benthebodyguard.com/images/thiefsprite.png)

I managed to replicate the page "as is" locally but whenever I try to customize it I lose some functionality or the animation get super weird.

Searching here in SO I found this http://jsfiddle.net/pGvgc/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var windowWidth = $(window).width();    
$("#block").css({ "right": windowWidth}); 

$(window).scroll(function(){       
    $("#block").css({ "right":  windowWidth  - $(window).scrollTop()});
});
});
```

but I don't understand how to control the start and stop of the scrolling and, even more important, how to animate the sprite dynamically changing the background position.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the element(#block in this case) when you scroll further. I want it to come from right and fix itself at the extreme right of the window. More like a "peep effect"

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar to benthebodyguard, and I've tried to find the best solution available. So far i've tried scripts like scrollpath, skrollr and crspline. But I've recently found raphael.js, and based on this [jsfiddle], I've decided to use if for the animation. Maybe it can help you also with your scroll animation. The sprite animation, at least for me, it will be a little more though since I have a more complex road that the character must follow!